# Is it possible to have two dogs in your home in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

The first dog I took to my house, my kids asked if they could keep him so I said yes and now he lives in my house.  I think that was Bran.  It was one of the Dawnguard dogs, anyway.

I now have Sceolang (the other Dawnguard dog) following me, but my kids never comment on him.  Does that mean I can't keep Sceolang in my home as well, or do I just have to wait a certain length of time before they'll ask about adopting him?

Answer (score 2):

Don't take my word for this, but I thinks you can have a pet per child , so therefore if one child owns bran, then the other should have a dialogue to have sceolang as a pet. If you speak to the child without the pet the it should have a dialogue option that Is the same or similar to how the first child got a pet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get two dogs.

One pet is for you to buy and the other pet is brought in by the child. Children will bring a pet home at random times.

But, **You** cannot get two pets.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 dog but you have to have 1 child make it get the first dog then get the next dog and after u get the second dog you adopt a second child who will ask for the dog as soon as you enter your house

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can only get 1 dog.

Also: my children are SO cruel I adopted bran and all I can hear is stupid dog, EVEN FROM LYDIA. They're going to bed early and I'm taking away their pet frostbite spider.

Comment: LOL I adopted Meeko after Vigilance died and I hear the same thing all the time too. It makes me so angry, so I do the same thing now.

Answer (score -1):

Well now I have 3 pets, and could have 4 :D First my son asked to keep a mudcrab, then my daughter wanted to keep a fox. The mudcrab died (accident) and I came home with sceolang, and my daughter asked to keep it (even tough she had the fox). Then I did the taste of death quest, but before I made sure to buy vigilance, and told him to wait at vlindrel hall. After I killed all the cannibals I came home, and told vigilance to go home, but since the guy who rents him is dead, vigilance just stayed living with us, and moving around like a normal pet, and getting the "stupid dog" dialogues.

Answer (score -2):

Sceolang is a dog your children can't adopt and won't comment on him. Only dawnguard dog you can adopt is bran.

Answer (score -2):

You can have either dog, just not both.  It isn't which dog that's the problem.  They'll only ask for the first one you bring.  It sucks.  I've been trying forever. but I've read that you can have one dog and eventually the other kid will ask for a wild animal.  So make sure you pick whichever dog you want in the house first.  You can travel with the second, but can't get a kid to ask for it.

Comment: You can't have 2 pets. They're separate.

Answer (score -2):

No, only one family pet (dog) allowed and I think one critter (mudcrab, fox, skeever, etc)

Comment: No, only one pet, not one of each.